# VirtualBox VM's menu not visible, can't insert Guest Additions media

Tags: gnome, virtualbox

Usually in VirtualBox I can insert a "Guest Addition CD image" by selecting a menu item. In the same menu I think I remember some view options were available, for instance to allow free resizing.

PROBLEM: I can't find that menu anymore:

[image]

Where is it hiding?

I am using VirtualBox 5.0.18_Ubuntu r106667 with Gnome on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

The [guest additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm) CD can only be mounted to an already exisiting virtual machine. This can be done in the machine's storage settings or much easier from the *Devices* menu of a **running VM**. To make the (global) menu visible the virtual machine needs to get focus.

[image]

Comment: My VM is running and has the focus (lower right of my screenshot). But still no menu is available.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul You may have to disable the GNOME AppMenu/globalMenu to be able to have the menus back on in the VM window. If that fails you may have to manually mount the ISO as shown in my answer I linked to.